# How to interact with webelement on popup while browser loader running?

Tags: selenium, automation

I have an authentication popup before loading the website and while popup display on the webpage and a loader display running on the browser it means webpage not loaded completely. 
And as per selenium if complete webpage not loaded initially, selenium not interact with elements

Need help on this.

Comment: can you provide the HTML or URL? also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

**Use following method**  with Java + Selenium  :

```
public boolean  isPageReady(WebDriver driver){
   boolean readyStateComplete = false;
    while (!readyStateComplete){
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        readyStateComplete = executor.executeScript("return document.readyState") == "complete";
    }
    return  readyStateComplete;
}
```

**For C# + Selenium** :

```
private void WaitUntilDocumentIsReady(TimeSpan timeout){
    var javaScriptExecutor = WebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, timeout);

    // Check if document is ready
    Func<IWebDriver, bool> readyCondition = webDriver => javaScriptExecutor
            .ExecuteScript("return (document.readyState == 'complete' && jQuery.active == 0)");
    wait.Until(readyCondition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until the page is completely loaded via JavaScript.

```
private void WaitUntilLoaded()
{
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until((x) =>
{
    return ((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.driver)
    .ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete");
});
}
```

Another option is to wait for a specific element(s) to be visible on the page

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
By.XPath("some Xpath")));
```

Source here: https://www.automatetheplanet.com/advanced-webdriver-tips-tricks-part-1/